# Importing imports within a function - Python 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have two files, `SysDump.py` and `libApi.py` in the same folder. 
In `SysDump` I do:

```
from libApi._SysDump import *
```

In `libApi` I have:

```
def _SysDump():
    import cPickle as _cPickle
    import math as _math
    from zipfile import ZipFile as _ZipFile
    import re as _re
```

However I get the error:

```
from libApi._SysDump import *
ImportError: No module named _SysDump
```

I use `VS2012+PTVS` to step through the code and the execution trace goes to `def _SysDump()` in `libApi` as I steop through but does not enter it. Question is how do I make this work in Python 2.6 only please?

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file? If not, you should be able to use `import SysDump`, then `SysDump._SysDump()`

Comment: Yes I do have __init__.py. Sorry I did not get it. What benefit I would get if I do import SysDump inside SysDump.py file? Kindly clarify

Comment: Ok open question to all. In python can you get part of a `function` as an import? I ask this because this _SysDump() is a function not a class where you can get a import a method or a variable

Comment: Note that functions starting with an underscore `_` are meant to be private and not exported.

Comment: One thing I should mention thanks to Crazyshezy. def _SysDump() does not work but class _SysDump() does work. Also Mark I do know the significance of _ but this is a special case so pardon me as I use _ contrary to its definition. However thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: I was too hasty. I have "from libApi import _SysDump" in SysDump.py and in libApi.py I have class _SysDump():. I am having class instead of def because def was not being seen. However the new problem is I have many classes inside libApi.py and it is seeing imports in other classes too!! Question is when I have specifically said from libApi import _SysDump why is it seeing imports within the other classes? Does Python have private and public concept? If so should I put in libApi.py "private class _SysDump():"?

Answer (score 2):

```
from libApi._SysDump import *
```

When writing this, Python looks for a package `libApi` and a module in it called `_SysDump`. A package is equivalent to a folder and a module is a single file. From your explanations, this is not the situation you have in your case. You have a module `libApi` with a function `_SysDump`. So if anything, you could do this:

```
from libApi import _SysDump
```

So you would get a reference to the `_SysDump` function. Note that running that function will not give you references to all the modules you are trying to import. Inside the function, the modules will be imported and assigned to local variables. After the function ends, those references are gone.

If you want to have some module take care of all your imports, you could make a file that performs those imports and import everything from that module:

```
# imports.py
import cPickle as _cPickle
import math as _math
from zipfile import ZipFile as _ZipFile
import re as _re
```

And then:

```
from imports import *
```

Comment: This worked. Specifically thanks for the explanation you taught me to fish:-). Problem solved!! Thanks